# Does Windows Phone 8.1 SDK require Visual Studio 2013 or can I use Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app in Visual Studio 2012. I want to migrate the app to Windows Phone 8.1. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2012 or do I need Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly this post from the Microsoft website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bg162891.aspx you can use the SDK and compile with a different version of Visual Studio but for debugging you need the 2013.

`The Windows SDK now includes support that enables the Visual Studio "Graphics Debugging" and "Graphics Frame Analysis" features for both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.
Note: These features require Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later.`

Answer (score 0):

There is no Seprate Sdk for `windows phone 8.1` unlike `windows phone 8.0` but instead of that The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are included with `Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2 or later)`. so you are needed to go for `Visual Studio 2013`. If you already have Visual Studio 2013 installed, use [this download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394245) to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC. If you don’t have Visual Studio 2013, you will need to install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows, which includes Update 2 RC, by using [this download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=395053)

If you want to use the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators you will need to install the [Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394354), which will adds six emulator images to an existing installation of Visual Studio.